# Assignability of Generic types?

Tags: c#

So this doesn't work:

```
    List<Object> j;  
    List<String> k =new  List<String>();
    j =  k;
```

Nor does this:

```
    j = (List<Object>)k;
```

or this:

```
   k = j as List<Object>;
```

It seems like these ought to be assignable, but not sure how is the right way to achieve the result

Comment: A list of object is not a list of string...

Comment: I understand, but if I can assign a string to an object variable why can't I assign a list<string> to a list<object>?

Comment: Use `j = k.Cast<object>().ToList();` You have to cast each `string` individually.

Comment: Let's say it worked. `j = k;`. What happens when you then do `j.Add(new Object());`? `j` is declared as `List<Object>` so it compiles. But at runtime, `j` is a `List<String>`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.